# Google Play Store Application is Rejected Saying : " Not adhering to Permissions policy"

Tags: android, google-play, privacy-policy

The application got rejected saying: "Not adhering to Permissions policy" not giving any particular reason as of why it has been rejected but received a mail saying

Action required: Provide instructions for app access
Here’s what to do to help get your app back on Google Play:

1. Provide access details for your app using the instructions described in this Play Console Help Center article under the “App Access” section.
   If your app typically requires a 2-Step Verification code or One Time Password, please provide us with reusable login credentials that do not expire through the Google Play Console.
   If your login credentials are not numeric or alphanumeric (for example, QR code, barcode), please generate a static URL and upload it to the Google Play Console.
2. Resubmit your app for review after double checking that it is compliant with the Developer Program Policies, including the Play Console Requirements.
   If your Update status is ‘Ready to send for review’, or if your Publishing overview has a section for ‘Changes ready to send for review’, then you must click ‘Send for review’ from the Publishing overview page to submit your changes for review.
   Note: You can complete these steps without contacting our policy support team.

But since the application is a Banking application which requires the user to be registered with the bank and hold a Account in the same bank to be able to Login, we are unable to provide credentials.
(Have already sent a appeal to play store saying the same but was asked to send login credentials none the less, and we have uploaded multiple app which was accepted by play store before, but this issue started occurring from December)

Can anybody give me a solution to this?

Comment: Set up reading from a json-file or an API call to your own server, so the app is directed to a sandbox environment with sandbox credentials (the bank must have such things) for the time of the review. In order for it to co-work with existing app (previous versions), make sure to only target specific version numbers with the redirected sandbox environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Open Play Console and go to the App content page (Policy > App
> content). Under "App access," select Start. Note: If you’ve previously
> added instructions for app access and you want to make changes, you’ll
> see and select Manage instead of Start. Click + Add new instructions
> and provide your access details. Note: Use the "Any other
> instructions" field to let us know if there’s anything special about
> your login mechanisms, such as using a one-time password, multi-factor
> authentication, or logins with more than two fields. Save your
> changes.

This for point (1)

Point (2) Are you track user location at the background

Comment: Thank You have done, what you said, the app is back in review. and yes app tracks Location.

Comment: The app was accepted and is on play store. Thank you :)

Comment: I have the same problem with one-time password authentication app using Otp   verification code! Please how can I provide them login credentials... Please help me

Comment: @KhalilHarar try to create a static phone number as a test number with static OTP code if you found the tested number and the OTP related to it login the user with test data then explain all of that for them in the instruction field